# how to get a new ephemeral IP address in google cloud without restarting vm?

Tags: web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, ip, virtual-machine

Context:

- I'm doing some scraping job and I need to change the IP address each time the IP get's blocked.
- I can't use [protocol-forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding) because this is only useful when trafic is being make to the vm NOT when the trafic is sent from the vm

I know I can create, change, delete static external IP address but it would be inefficient if I do this multiple times that is why I would like to change the ephemeral IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by following this process:

- Go to your VM detail
- Click on Edit
- Go to network interface and click on the pencil
- Select none for external IP
- Click on Done
- Scroll down and click on Save.

(wait during the update of the VM). Then:

- Click again on Edit
- Go to network interface and click on the pencil
- Select Ephemeral for external IP
- Click on Done
- Scroll down and click on Save.

Comment: by in that case it get's the same IP address as before

Comment: I performed the test before answering you, and I juste performed it again. The IP are different. The refresh button don't work correctly, use refresh or your browser. I update my answer to be more clear on the process.

Comment: I tried but same IP address.

Comment: It's a pool of IP, you can get the same as before, try again, Maybe let few minutes before requesting a new public IP.